# what does it mean a red filename shown with black background?

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I have a compilation problem, and when I check my lib/ directory I get this output from "ls":

[image: ls output]

What the red/black combination mean?

I checked in the output of "dircolors -p" as suggested here ([What does it mean for the file name to be shown with red background](https://superuser.com/q/202783/193693)), but I could not find an answer.

Moreover, what the question marks at the place of permissions/user/size/timestamp mean?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you have there is a dangling symlink, or a symlink pointing to a file or directory which no longer exists.

A symlink itself really has no filesize, because it isn't a file. Symlinks are stored [within the inodes themselves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Storage_of_symbolic_links), meaning they have no real contents or size, but are instead pointers to other files on the disk.

The output of `file libCLHEP-Exceptions-2.1.3.1.a` should reveal where it's pointing to.

Comment: `ls -l` should also print the symlink target, which it doesn't seem to do here.

Comment: This is true in most cases, but I've seen it fail to do that in a couple of obscure circumstances. `file` is usually a lot better at working out what's going on with a particular, erm, file.

Comment: Many thanks Xyon, I didn't know the `file` command: it's very useful indeed. +1!

Answer (score 3):

At the first look, it does look like a broken link, but since it is supposed to be a regular file, it might be a file system corruption. Try to do a `fsck` on the file system and then try to delete this file if it is still there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stefan, +1. Actually I tried to remove the broken link, but `rm` gave a "no such file or directory" error. was very strange, actually, because the link was broken, the file not there, and `rm` still refused to delete the link... Anyway, I removed the whole folder, and that fixed the problem.